# Secure UDP based protocol

Tags: безопасность, udp, protocol

Здравствуйте! 
Занимаюсь созданием клиент-серверного приложения, к которому предъявлены следующие требования: 
1) Часть данных должна передаваться с минимальными задержками(realtime). 
2) Гарантируется конфиденциальность этих realtime-данных (сложно прочесть постороннему лицу).
3) Гарантируется аутентификация этих данных (подлинность авторства легко проверить).
4) Гарантируется целостность (пакет либо не пришёл, либо пришёл в неизменном виде).

Первому пункту, очевидно, удовлетворяет UDP протокол. Для удовлетворения остальных трёх необходимо над этим UDP создать более высокоуровневый протокол, и это трудоёмкая задача.

В связи с этим - вопрос. Существуют ли **Opensource & Secure & Fast** протоколы передачи данных?

Гугл выдаёт  UDT, который не является secure, и ещё несколько малоизвестных протоколов, про которые мало информации, например, Tsunami UDP.

Особенно буду рад, если вы сами пробовали что-либо подобное - в этом случае прошу поделиться опытом.

Comment: [DTLS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTLS)?

Comment: Спасибо! Видимо, это то, что нужно